# Query database related variables in JDO

Tags: mysql, jdo

I need to get some database related variables like `gtid_executed`, it's convenient to get this value from mysql via query statement like below:

```sh
show global variables like "gtid_executed";
```

the result in mysql:

```
mysql> show global variables like "gtid_executed";
+---------------+--------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name | Value                                      |
+---------------+--------------------------------------------+
| gtid_executed | 2270cb64-37a1-11ec-a47a-0242ac110002:1-190 |
+---------------+--------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I want do this query from `JDO` likes below:

```java
PersistenceManagerFactory pmf = JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory("Tutorial");

PersistenceManager pm = pmf.getPersistenceManager();

String queryText = "show global variables like gtid_executed";
Query query = pm.newQuery("javax.jdo.query.SQL", queryText);
Object res = query.execute();
```

But this exception occured:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.jdo.JDOUserException: 
You have specified an SQL statement ("show global variables like gtid_executed") that doesnt start with SELECT. 
This is invalid.
```

How can I do query like `show variables ***` in `JDO` gracefully? Or any other good methods in replace is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the workaround:

- First method is set `datanucleus.query.sql.allowAll` as `true` for persistence-unit properties:

```xml
<property name="datanucleus.query.sql.allowAll" value="true"/>
```

- Second method is use `jdbc query`:

```java
// use native jdbc for query not begin with select
Connection conn = (Connection) pm.getDataStoreConnection().getNativeConnection();
String queryText = "show global variables like \"gtid_executed\"";
Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(queryText);
```